# Text for auto save option

Tags: gui-design, labels

I have a UI on a thick client which has a textbox to enter number of minutes. These number of minutes are used by the application to determine when should the save operation be performed. Like if a user enters 5, the save operation is performed every 5 minutes. I am confused as to what text should the label of this textbox have. I am attaching an image just for clarity sake.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, It looks good, but unless the requirements ask for decimals in the minutes, I's just use integer numbers (5 instead of 5.0).

In our application we have

"Autosave every [5   ] minute(s)"

Comment: Thanks for your inputs [Max](http://ux.stackexchange.com/users/10623/max).

Answer (score 0):

What I don't like in your box, is the decimal point.

Due to the fact that a minute has 60, not 100 seconds, many people might find filling fractions of a minutes counter-intuitive.

While 5 minutes and a half is easy, what about the situation if for some reason, somebody wanted the auto-save to run every 5 minutes and 10 seconds?

What I would proposes, it either splitting the two: minutes and seconds between two fields, or leaving only one of them to be specified.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs [DiH](http://ux.stackexchange.com/users/26066/dih).